# Edit wordpress menú from mysql query

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I'm trying to insert / modify / delete items from a Wordpress menu from a MYSQL query in a separate WordPress file.
Does anyone know how wordpress menus work at the database level?

Answer (score 0):

They're nothing else than a default postype, specifically:  **nav_menu_item**.

So like the rest of the postypes they are in the **post** table or **wp_posts** if you use that prefix.

As all the rest of postypes their meta values are stored in **postmeta**/**wp_postsmeta** with the corresponding id.